# When someone places a flyer on your car windshield without your permission, is s/he Masig G'vul?

Tags: halacha, choshen-mishpat-civil-law, vehicles-transportation

On several occasions, a Jewish boy has placed a flyer about some neighborhood business or tzedaka foundation on my car windshield. Since I don't want the flyer there, is s/he "Masig G'vul" (losely translated as "overtaking the border or one's property"?

Comment: Are you asking if the boy is wrongfully misappropriating the space on your windshield that the flyer takes up? Is there precedent for the placement of a paper on real estate constituting a violation of this law?

Comment: @WAF - I believe that "masig g'vul" applies to property in general, not just real estate. I may be mistaken on that assumption.

Comment: If one is makpid put a sign in your car saying no soliciting on windshield,as for everyone else its a davar miut most ppl don't care they just throw it out without thinking